# Why doesn't old Spock travel to the nearby Federation outpost on his own?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-trek-2009

In Star Trek (2009), Spock is captured by Romulans and abandoned on a planet (or moon, seemingly) near Vulcan, from which he later watches

> the destruction of his home world.

The timing is unclear but it seems he has been there for some time and established residence in a cave, knowledge of local life-forms, etc. He also knows that there is a Federation outpost nearby (I think they said 15km or 20km,

> he is later able to walk it with young Kirk).

Why does he hang out in his cave in the first place? Why not return to the Federation from the start?

Comment: I assume because he's trying to preserve the current timeline.

Comment: I'd have to watch again, but I do believe that @Paulie_D is correct. He only leaves once Kirk convinces him to do so and he feels it's now the best course of action.

Comment: Keep in mind that, in TOS, "old Spock" engaged in time travel a few times and saw situations where taking *any* action - [even one that seems noble and well-meaning](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_City_on_the_Edge_of_Forever_(episode)), like *saving a single life* - could have disastrous consequences for the future.